# Solution for a recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations

Need hints/solution to solve for *a* in terms of *n* in the equation:

$$a = \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{a}$$

---

I'm actually trying to get and solve the recurrence for the following piece of code:

```
while (n > 1)
{
    n = (long)Math.Sqrt(n);
    // do something
}
```

I felt that for this piece of code:

$$T(n) = \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{T(n)}$$

and hence arrived at the equation above by writing T(n) = a.

Comment: Did you mean $a = \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{a}$?

Comment: @dxiv: Exactly. Is my question too bogus?

Comment: Hint: let $\sqrt{a} = b >= 0$ then you get a simple quadratic in $b$. P.S. I edited your question to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which looks better and is more easily understood around here.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried subtracting $\sqrt a$ from both sides and squaring?  Why not?  You wind up with an equation with only one square root-that is progress.  dxiv has a good idea as well.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Updated my question to answer your question.

Comment: @dxiv: Thanks for the edit. I have updated the question.

Comment: What you posted (a) is an equation *not* a recurrence, and (b) doesn't match the code fragment.

Comment: @dxiv: Can you explain (b)?

Comment: Your edit does not show what you have tried.  It is also not correct.  Where does the $\sqrt{T(n)}$ come from?

Comment: `n = (long)Math.Sqrt(n);` would be the recurrence $T(n+1) = \lfloor \sqrt{T(n)} \rfloor$ (but of course you don't show what comes after that line of code). I seriously suggest you run the code step by step for a few iterations, understand what it's doing, and figure out what your question really is before posting.

Comment: @RossMillikan: This equation has come from my attempt to analyze this code. I see that I'm wrong about the recurrence. I'm able to express it in words, but not in terms of variables. The run time of the code is equal to the number of times the input can be taken square root of, as it reaches 1.

Comment: @dxiv: What comes in `//do something` is independent of _n_. Hence omitted. My exact question is to understand the time complexity of the code above. Unfortunately such a question is not properly answered on SO. So, I came to MSE.

Comment: @dxiv: If you can write an answer, outlining how my approach is wrong and explaining how to solve the correct recurrence, that would be very kind.

Comment: What do you do when $\sqrt n$ is not an integer?  Do you round down?  Or up? I'm sorry for the aggression, but if you (think you) can express it in words but not variables you can't express it precisely.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I round up because I have to run the loop one more time. Is my simple english explanation incorrect?

Comment: @RossMillikan That looks like `C` notation, in which case the `(long)` cast truncates (rounds down a la $\lfloor x \rfloor$). P.S. [displayName] The code you posted does *not* round *up*.

Comment: @dxiv: It's C#. _n_ is long itself. I wasn't sure - so just read - about the cast from Double to long. Usually when calculating time complexity we aren't that strict because constants are ignored. If we are really strict, I agree the code will result in truncation of the precision and round down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, saying do something is fixed in time, the correct recurrence is $T(n)=1+T(\sqrt n)$  You make one run through with the variable being $\sqrt n$ and then restart. You have not specified what happens when $\sqrt n$ is not an integer. Do you round down, up, or ???.  Leaving aside the rounding issues, you should think about what happens to $n=2^k$ where $k$ is a power of $2$

Comment: Thank you for your response. That brings me to the question - how is such a recurrence solved? Hints should suffice if you mind giving away the answer. Not a homework question - Just trying to solve another question on SO.

Comment: Ok.. So T(n) = Log(Log(n)). Thanks.