# Solve a recurrence : $T(n) = ( \sqrt{n} + 1)*T( \sqrt{n}) + 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

How can the below recurrence be solved?

$T(n) = (    \sqrt{n} + 1)T(    \sqrt{n}) + 1$ and $T(2) = 1$.

I have tried the master method, but have failed!!Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you so much for editing it, i was struggling to do it!!

Comment: Define "*solve*". Are you looking for a closed form for $T(n)$ (unlikely), or an approximation, or asymptotic behavior, or ...?

Comment: my bad!!I am trying to find the asymptotic behavior!!

Comment: Sounds eerily familiar ([Solution for a recurrence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952902/solution-for-a-recurrence#comment4009388_1952902)). Like in the other question, this recursion only allows you to calculate $T(n)$ for $n=2^{2^k}$. You can still derive some asymptotic behavior from that. FWIW the first iterations give $1,4,21,358$ which match [A048164](http://oeis.org/A048164).

Comment: I am still not getting it!!i have been trying since yesterday!!This thread gave me a hint, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239402/solve-the-recurrence-relation-tn-sqrtn-t-left-sqrt-n-right-n!!But i still couldn't do it!Thanks for the help anyway!!Will try till i find a solution!!

Comment: Please do ***not*** change the question to a different one, especially ***after*** answers have been posted which do in fact answer your original question, but no longer apply once you changed it. If you have a new/different question, just post it as a new/different question.

Comment: Yes!!I am really sorry about that!!I wasn't gonna edit it permanently!!Me and my friend were trying to play around with the recurrence equation and i forgot to revert it back!!I am extremely sorry!!The answer you gave was perfect!!

Comment: I am really sorry about it!!This is very embarrassing!!I will never try to do it again

Comment: I'll undo my downvote once you rollback the edit to the original question. As a matter of general etiquette, it's frowned upon to change the question in ways that leave pre-existing legitimate answers or comments look silly all of a sudden.

Comment: Yes!!I totally understand how wrong it was to do what i did!!But i assure you, it was totally unintentional!!Please do not rollback the down vote!!I am extremely sorry for what i did!!

Comment: No problem. The original question is in fact interesting on its own. The **"** $-$ **"** variation thereof is, too, but that's worth a separate question. I don't see an obvious "shortcut" for that other one.

Comment: Yes!! "-" variation is harder than this one!!We have been trying to solve that one too!!So if we don't end up with a solution for that, we will definitely post it as a separate question!!The idea of telescoping made us change the sign from + to - and try to solve the question!!

Comment: My first guess is that $T(n)=(\sqrt{n}+a)T(\sqrt{n})+b$ would still give a $T(n) = \Theta(n)$ but that's just a random guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recurrence can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{T(n)}{n-1} = \frac{T(\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n} - 1} + \frac{1}{n-1}$$

or, with:

$$n = 2^{2^k} \quad\text{and}\quad C(k)= \frac{T(2^{2^k})}{2^{2^k} - 1}$$

as:

$$C(k) = C(k-1) + \frac{1}{2^{2^k}-1}$$

and after telescoping $C(k) - C(k-1)$:

$$C(k) = C(0) + \sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{1}{2^{2^j}-1}$$

The latter series converges (by the ratio test, for example), so the limit exists:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} C(k) = C$$

It follows that $T(2^{2^k}) \sim C \cdot (2^{2^k} - 1)$ asymptotically, so in the end $T(n) = \Theta(n)$.

Comment: Hey, do you mind explaining the last line of your analysis?I am kind of stuck at the last line

Comment: Reverting to the $n$ notation, $\frac{T(n)}{n-1} = C(\log_2 \log_2 n)$ by the definition of $C(\cdot)$. But the RHS has limit $C$ at infinity, so $\frac{T(n)}{n-1} = \Theta(1)$ which implies $T(n) = \Theta(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(k) = T(2^{2^k})$, so that we have
$$F(k+1) = (2^{2^k}+1)F(k) + 1$$
and $F(0) = 1$. The generating function for $F$ is
\begin{align}
S(x) = &\ \sum_{k\ge0}F(k)x^k\\
= &\ 1 + \sum_{k\ge0}((2^{2^k}+1)F(k)+1)x^{k+1}\\
= &\ 1 + xS(x) + \frac{1}{1-x} - 1 + \sum_{k\ge1}2^{2^k}F(k)x^{k+1}\\
= &\ xS(x) + \frac{1}{1-x} + \sum_{k\ge0}2^{2^k}F(k)x^{k+1}.
\end{align}
Now let $C_0 = 2$ and $C_i = 2^{2^{i-1}}(2^{2^{i-1}}-1)$, so that
$$2^{2^k} = \sum_{i=0}^kC_i.$$
Using this and what done above, we write
\begin{align}
S(x) = &\ xS(x) + \frac{1}{1-x} + \sum_{k\ge0}2^{2^k}F(k)x^{k+1}\\
= &\ xS(x) + \frac{1}{1-x} + \sum_{i\ge0}C_i\sum_{k\ge i}F(k)x^{k+1}.
\end{align}
I don't know how to treat the last term, so I'll leave it up to you (or any volunteers).

---

You could also try to apply the master theorem to $G(\ell) = T(2^\ell)$, but from the question I assume you have already tried this.